# Convert string "\ u0026" to "&" in C ++

Tags: c++, string, replace

I'm getting a string from a Post but the string comes like this:

?re=784D30879\u0026rr=POH0525\u0026tt=525.100000\u0026id=0958567C-20DC-44B4-9FD0-1AD13453DEBF4

And i want:

?re=784D30879&rr=POH0525&tt=525.100000&id=0958567C-20DC-44B4-9FD0-1AD13453DEBF4

I am using a function to replace characters in a String but it sends me the following error: `a universal character name cannot designate a character in the basic character set`

So I'm calling the function:

```
message = replaceChars(message, string("\u0026"), string("&"));
```

And this is the function:

```
string replaceChars(string stringToChange, const string& charToChange, const string& newChar) 
{
    size_t initialPosition = 0;

    while((initialPosition= stringToChange.find(charToChange, initialPosition)) != string::npos) 
    {
        stringToChange.replace(initialPosition, charToChange.length(), newChar);
        initialPosition += newChar.length();
    }

    return stringToChange;
}
```

I cant understand the error.

Comment: Where are you getting the string from, and is it possible to get it to *not* escape ampersands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `"\\u0026"` instead of `"\u0026"`